# Android/Kotlin - Accessing assets folder from a top-level function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, assets, android-context

In my app, I put helper methods in the top level, not contained in any class, so I can call any of them from anywhere. And I have an assets folder (app/src/main/assets) with text files in it.

I get access to this folder inside Main Activity using this code

```
val file: String = applicationContext.assets.open("folderInAssets/filename.txt").bufferedReader().use {
        it.readText()
}
```

However, it seems that I cannot access the assets folder from outside activities or classes. `applicationContext` is not defined, and I cannot have access to a `Context`. I also tried

```
Application().assets.open(...)
```

but it gives me the error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.Context.getAssets()' on a null object reference

My Question: How can I get access to the folder from a top-level function in Kotlin? And is there a preferable "Kotlinic" way to define helper methods in an app?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Share an URI to it. Read up on `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`

Comment: Pass the context to your function?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari I thought about it, but there should be a more abstract way.